# Файл Sitemap

Tags: оптимизация, вёрстка, sitemap

Вот сделал файл сайтмап по гугловской справке

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns:image="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc></loc>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>http://site/19.jpg</image:loc>
        </image:image>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>http://site/15.jpg</image:loc>
        </image:image>
```

Но потом сам Google просит изменить

```
xmlns:image="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1
```

на

```
xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1"
```

Но Яндекс вообще не понимает тег image - что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отдавай ботам разные сайтмэпы